# Referring back to something

Tags: single-word-requests

I frequently read a column (or such) that begins the text by mentioning a particular item/person/anecdote or similar, and then continues to lay out the subject and in the end refers back to the "thing" in the beginning of the text. Is there a particular word or phrase to describe this concept?

Just to drop a single reference, see how "Steve  Jobs" is used in this article: [I bought my Mom a Chromebook Pixel](http://www.theverge.com/2016/2/1/10884918/i-bought-my-mom-a-chromebook-pixel-the-divergence)

Comment: Maybe *setup* (the first, almost casual, mentions of Jobs) and *callback* (the final line which uses a reference to him to tie everything up with a bow. Or you could say the article comes *full circle*.

Comment: Taking the second suggestion in Silenus's comment, another variant of it is: the conclusion *circles back* to the introduction.

Comment: Don't you call that "referring back" to something?

Comment: I am thinking, since it's a common concept, there might be an actual word or phrase for it among journalists/writers.

Comment: A SWR for "Referring back to something" is *aforementioned*. The title needs work: *SWR for the concept of continually referring back to aforementioned subject matter?* At SE we call it *on-topic.*

Answer (score 1):

The concept is called **persuasive writing**, of which my English teacher absolutely drilled* into us the five paragraph format for:

- Introduction
- Body (three or more paragraphs)
- Conclusion

The conclusion is basically a rewrite of the introduction, that includes the TL;DR versions of the body's answers or reasoning.

> Every essay or paper designed to be persuasive needs a paragraph at the very outset introducing both the subject at hand and the thesis which is being advanced. It also needs a final paragraph summarizing what's been said and driving the author's argument home. –Writing Guide: Introduction and Conclusion; [usu.edu](http://www.usu.edu/markdamen/WritingGuide/24intro.htm)

The title, "Why and how to convince (you and) your mom to buy a Pixel Tablet," wouldn't be as <strike>catchy</strike> *persuasive*. Furthermore, if you condense all of these into a single concise paragraph, you've created the article's *abstract*. This is where you'd find words like *hitherto* and *aforementioned* (which is what I though you were after).

I personally found this writing style indispensable for science fair papers which also have an introduction (problem), as well as a body (procedure) that is to be persuasively backed up with data (results), the culmination of which can be found in the conclusion, and the TL:DR version of the whole thing: an abstract.

---

** Take a look at the (1-3-1) formatting of my answer above the block quote: There's this(1). Here's what it is(2–4). Here's why there is this(5).

Introduction: "by mentioning a particular item/person/anecdote or similar" (1)

Body: "continues to lay out the subject" (2–4)

Conclusion: "and in the end refers back to the "thing" in the beginning of the text" (5)

Comment: In conclusion, [link to this answer].

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are talking about, but this might lead you to the answer:

anaphora: (Greek:, "carrying back") is emphasizing words by repeating them at the beginnings of neighboring clauses. In contrast, an epiphora is repeating words at the clauses' ends

```
It was the best of times, 
it was the worst of times,
... 
we were all going direct to Heaven, 
we were all going direct the other way 
— Charles Dickens, A Tale of Two Cities
```

Answer (score 0):

It has the prosaic name *circular structure* or *circular narrative style*.

> A story that ends in the same place it began is commonly called a circular or cyclical narrative.
>   [- Elissa Hansen, Demand Media, What Is a Circular Narrative Style?](http://classroom.synonym.com/circular-narrative-style-3143.html)